# Matlab method for converting object to string

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I have an object, `Person p;`. The following properties are `p`'s properties:

```
Properties:
     PersonName: 'John Doe'
     JobType: [1x1 JobTypes]
```

JobType is an object from `JobTypes` class which contains enumeration of JobTypes. I want to see `JobType: Manager` instead of `JobType: [1x1 JobTypes]`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never been fond of enumeration classes in Matlab -- just too much hassle for my taste. Therefore, I have too little experience to *truly* understand what's going on here. 
Nevertheless, I'm going to try: an enumeration class only has a value. It is *not* a string. Things like

```
J = JobTypes.Manager
```

will assign a `JobTypes` class object to the variable `J`, set to the value associated with `Manager`. This value is chosen by Matlab's internals, and will never be shown to the user. The fact that it displays nicely as `J = Manager` on the command line, is due to Matlab's standard `disp` and `display` implementations for enumeration classes. I **think** this method does not work properly in combiation with a call to `display` from within another class.

To circumvent this, you could define your own `display` method for your `Person`:

```
classdef Person < handle

    properties
        PersonName = 'John Doe'
        JobType  = JobTypes.Manager
    end

    methods       
        function  display(self)   
            fprintf(...
                ['Properties:\n',...
                '   Personname: ''%s''\n',...
                '      JobType: %s\n'],...
                   self.PersonName,...
                   self.JobType.char);            
        end
    end

end
```

`JobType.char` is Matlab's version of a `toString` for enumeration classes, so inserting it in `fprintf` will show the actual string! (kudos to @zagy for this)

Take a look at how the Mathworks has implemented the `display` methods of some of their own classes to get a feel for how to get the links to Superclasses, Methods, Events, etc. in the display.

Comment: I believe one can use `JobTypes.char` property to return the appropriate string rather than using a `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to overwrite the `display(obj)` and `disp(obj)` methods of your class to achieve this.

Maybe these two pages help: [1](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/br2vkg7.html),[2](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/display.html)